# MySQL, CONCAT, the result is null sometimes

Tags: php, mysql

Im putting big data to table, to a `LONGBLOB` field. First I create the record:

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1, '');
```

then in a `foreach` cycle I put the sliced data:

```
foreach (str_split($content, 1024*512) as $item)
{
    UPDATE mytable SET BIGCONTENT = CONCAT(BIGCONTENT, $item) WHERE ID = 1;
}
```

yes, the field is growing, but after a few turn, (its about 1MB) it becomes `null`! I tried another way:

```
UPDATE mytable SET BIGCONTENT = CONCAT_WS("", BIGCONTENT, $item) WHERE ID = 1;
```

still the same. Whats the problem?

Comment: what is `field`  ? Column name , or some value ?

Comment: column name, yes. I edit the question

Comment: What would be `$item` , give example like $item can be 12345678 etc.

Comment: I make another question, this is not so clear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936310/mysql-concat-the-result-is-null-after-a-while