# MySQL, CONCAT, the result is null after a while

Tags: mysql

Im putting big data to table, to a `LONGBLOB` field, but as the table grows, the field becomes empty. Code:

```
mysql_query ('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testtable (content LONGBLOB NOT NULL) ENGINE = MyISAM');
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE testtable');
mysql_query('REPLACE INTO testtable VALUES (".")');
$bigData = str_repeat('A', 1024*1024*2); // 2 MB!
foreach (str_split($bigData, 1024*64) as $item)
{
    mysql_query ('UPDATE testtable SET content = CONCAT(content, "'.mysql_real_escape_string($item).'")');
    $rec = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query ('SELECT content FROM testtable'));
    echo 'Size of the content: '.strlen($rec[0]).'<br>';
}
```

The output:

```
Size of the content: 65537
Size of the content: 131073
Size of the content: 196609
Size of the content: 262145
Size of the content: 327681
Size of the content: 393217
Size of the content: 458753
Size of the content: 524289
Size of the content: 589825
Size of the content: 655361
Size of the content: 720897
Size of the content: 786433
Size of the content: 851969
Size of the content: 917505
Size of the content: 983041
Size of the content: 0
Size of the content: 65536
Size of the content: 131072
Size of the content: 196608
```

Whats happening? LONGBLOB should take more data than that.

Comment: If you want to know the length of the field in the database, use `select length(content) from testtable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the `max_allowed_packet` size.

It looks like it is failing at 1MB, and according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html the default max packet size is 1MB:

> The server's default max_allowed_packet value is 1MB. You can increase this if the server needs to handle big queries

Set the value in the `my.cnf` file, e.g.:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

#### In PHP

If you don't have access to the MySQL config you could try setting via a query (note: I've not checked if this will work).

```
$db->query( 'SET @@global.max_allowed_packet = 16777216' );
```

Comment: indeed. This CONCAT method was just to avoid this error, e.g. I cant insert this 2MB at once, but separated, now it also fails too *sobbing

Comment: is there mightbe any way, to insert that big data if I cant edit the setting of server?

Comment: @JohnSmith Try changing the setting through PHP as per my update - it might work. If not you might have to store your data as 1MB chunks and recombine after you've retrieved them from the db.